# R plotRGB function color differences in picture after removing value

Tags: r, r-raster

I have three png's and plot them as RGB as follows:

```
TCI = function(channel1,channel2,channel3){
r = raster::raster(channel1)
g = raster::raster(channel2)
b = raster::raster(channel3)
RGB_brick= raster::brick(r,g,b)
RGB_brick[RGB_brick<1] = NA
graphics::par(bg=NA,mar=c(0,0,0,0),oma=c(0,0,0,0))
raster::plotRGB(RGB_brick,r=1,g=2,b=3,stretch="lin",bgalpha=0)
```

}

The output looks like this:

[image]

If I take `RGB_brick[RGB_brick<1] = NA` out, the result looks like this:

[image]

I did `RGB_brick[RGB_brick<1] = NA` because I want to remove the black background. Now the problem is that there are slightly color differences between the two images. How could i solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. Your second image is "the desired output", except for the "black background". But isn't that what your first example shows?

Please restate your question using data we all have access to. For example,

```
library(raster)
b <- brick(system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster"))
plotRGB(b)
```

Changing small values to `NA` does not change the colors

```
b[b<100] <- NA
plotRGB(b)
```

Unless you stretch the values, as you do with `stretch="lin"`

```
plotRGB(b, stretch="lin")
```

To avoid that, you could perhaps stretch the values yourself, and use plotRGB without the stretch argument.

Comment: I edited the question. Unfortunately, the problem does not occur with the R logo. Here, just the 0 values are set to NA, but in my image, it looks like the values are mapped to 0 again.

Comment: I solved my problem by defining a rescale function which maps the specified values of min and max to 0 and 255 again. Now I get the desired TCI.